# Script to find, replace and save xlsx file

Tags: python, excel, vba

I have a requirement I need find, replace and Save As  to create multiple .xlxs Excel sheet from one sheet, the requirement is wherever I find a text "202" replace it with (203......290) and *save as* with same name.

I wrote a code in python where I am successfully able to replace the string and save the file, but the problem is as below:

1. On Blank cells now `"None"` is printed.
2. If I put  a `if` condition `if s=="None"`:
   `ws.cell(r,c).value=s.replace("None",str(''))`
   I am successfully able to see blank cells but other cells which has none value originally is now blank.
3. Any integer value is also like string.

```
import openpyxl
from openpyxl.utils.cell import get_column_letter
for value in range(204, 205):
    wb=openpyxl.load_workbook("location of script\\sample.xlsx")
    for i in wb.sheetnames:
        ws = wb[i]
        for r in range(1,ws.max_row+1):
            for c in range(1,ws.max_column+1):
                s=str(ws.cell(r,c).value)
                if s=="None":
                    ws.cell(r,c).value=s.replace("None",str(''))

                elif "202 in s":
                    ws.cell(r,c).value=s.replace("202",str(value))
                    print("row{} col{}: {}".format(r,c,s))
                
    wb.save("location of script"+str(value)+'sample'+'.xlsx') .
```

Request you to please help me to edit code so that I can following requirement:

1. Blank cell should not have any value.
2. Cells which are Integer should remain integer
3. or if you other suggestion like writing Macro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My take on this. Using pandas may be more efficient and seems a bit simpler.

```
import pandas as pd

filename = "File.xlsx"

value_to_replace = 202
new_value = 269

df = pd.read_excel(filename)

for column in range(df.shape[1]):
    col_name = df.columns[column]
    df.loc[df[col_name] == value_to_replace, col_name] = new_value

df.to_excel(filename, index=False)
```

It overwrites the current excel sheet.

In order to read a sheet and save to a different file you need to use:

```
df = pd.read_excel(filename_input, sheet_name="Sheet1")
df.to_excel(filename_output, sheet_name="Sheet1")
```

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html

Comment: two questions: 1. can it works on multiple worksheet or tabs in same excel sheet and I want to create new file , I don't want to overwrite

Comment: It works on multiple sheets too, you need to pass in the sheetname as parameter when reading. If you want to create a new file, just change the filename from df.to_excel to any filepath.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Ducu for help, now its working for me.

```
import openpyxl
from openpyxl.utils.cell import get_column_letter
for value in range(207, 208):
    wb=openpyxl.load_workbook("Location")
    for i in wb.sheetnames:
        ws = wb[i]
        for r in range(1,ws.max_row+1):
            for c in range(1,ws.max_column+1):
                s=ws.cell(r,c).value
                #print(type(s))
                #print(s)
                if s is None or isinstance(s, int):
                    print(s)
                elif '202' in str(s):
                    ws.cell(r,c).value=s.replace("202",str(value))
                    #print("row{} col{}: {}".format(r,c,s))
                
    wb.save("Location"+str(value)+'Sample'+'.xlsx')
```

Comment: That's great! Glad I could help. Could you maybe pick my answer as correct though? Extra points are much appreciated :)